# Duda con re.VERBOSE de Regex en python

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

estaba armando un buscador en python con la libreria regex estaba buscando un str en un archivo txt yo utilice la siguiente estructura:

```
buscador=re.compile(r'''
cita"
([a-zA-Z0-9=°ñÑ \. \% \+ \- \& \* \$ \{ \} \( \) \[ \] \? \| \' \" \/ \, \< \> \s]+)
"
''',re.VERBOSE)
x=buscador.search(txt)
```

Y con esta estructura no me conseguía la cita aun cuando probé con un `txt='''cita"ejemplo-de cualquier cosa" 123'''` y al hacer `print(x)` me mostraba una list vacía, despues de un par de intentos resumí mi codigo a 1 linea sin utilizar el `re.VERBOSE`:

```
Hunter=re.compile(r'''meta name="title" content="([a-zA-Z0-9=°ñÑ \. \% \+ \- \& \* \$ \{ \} \( \) \[ \] \? \| \' \" \/ \, \< \> \s]+)"''')
```

Y esto sin me dio el str buscado dentro de mi list, mi pregunta es porque el `re.VERBOSE` afecto en mi búsqueda y como realmente influye en ella porque tenia entendido que el `re.VERBOSE` era para poder escribir en varias lineas lo que se quiere buscar para poder leerlo de manera mas cómoda? a caso no funciona asi, por favor quiero saber en que influye y porque su uso, gracias de antemano

Answer (score 1):

El uso de `re.VERBOSE` no solo afecta a los saltos de linea, permite dos cosas:

- Usar comentarios dentro de la expresión con `#` (igual que en el código). Tras un `#` no escapado se ignora todo el texto siguiente hasta encontrar un salto de línea.
- Los espacios en blanco que no formen parte de un clase de caracteres (como `\w`), tokens como `*?` o estén escapados serán ignorados. Esto significa que podemos formatear la expresión con los espacios en blanco que queramos para hacerla más legible sin que afecte a la misma.

Claro, esto implica a su vez dos cosas:

- Hay que escapar cualquier carácter `#` que forma parte de la propia expresión en si.
- Hay que escapar todo espacio que forme parte de la expresión en si misma (`\`, `\s`, `[ ]`, `\t`, ...), excepto los casos antes comentados.

Si no se escapan el patrón se verá modificado porque serán ignorados.

La expresión:

```
r'''meta name="title" content="
([a-zA-Z0-9=°ñÑ \. \% \+ \- \& \* \$ \{ \} \( \) \[ \] \? \| \' \" \/ \, \< \> \s]+)"'''
```

quedaría realmente como:

```
r'''metaname="title"content="([a-zA-Z0-9=°ñÑ\.\%\+\-\&\*\$\{\}\(\)\[\]\?\|\'\" \/\,\<\>\s]+)"'''
```

Para que no se viera afectada debería ser:

```
r'''
meta\sname="title"\scontent="
([a-zA-Z0-9=°ñÑ \. \% \+ \- \& \* \$ \{ \} \( \) \[ \] \? \| \' \" \/ \, \< \> \s]+)
```